# Activate an input tag on the click on a image "modify"

Tags: javascript, php, html, aide

I am coding a website in which admin has access to a dashboard page where they can see the list of users. I would like to add the ability for the admin to change other users’ roles in the same line.

Here is the code:

```
<table>
<caption> Liste des utilisateurs </caption>
<tr class="title">
    <th>Date de création</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Nom d'utilisateur</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
    <th>Rôle</th>
    <th>Id</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>username</td>
    <td>*****@mail.fr</td>
    <td>admin</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier"> 
</tr> 
 
<tr>
    <td>2022-05-08 09:29:53</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>username</td>
    <td>****@mail.fr</td>
    <td>user</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier"> 
</tr>
</table>
```

But I have two problems:

1. I don't know how to change  `<td>` to `<input>` when someone clicks on an image; maybe with JavaScript?
2. Even if I make it, how can I limit the change to only that line, and not all the `<td>`. I use a forEach loop in php to generate this code. So I can't really generate the code with each line personalised.

I need your help. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions should be asked in english on this site.

Comment: @PMF I changed my question in english. Thanks for the reminder ;)

Comment: @romain: could you also translate the title, as that's likely to either prevent people from reading your question, or attracting people with the intent of closing the question because it's not written in English.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Thanks for pinging me. I've started using the Follow feature for situations like this but forgot to in this case.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I think it would be helpful if you showed (part of) the code that generates this html.

Comment: You cannot just *"change TD to INPUT"* because that would lead to broken HTML markup of your TABLE

Comment: Also, IMG tag is not allowed as a child of TR. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches, here, the first is to explicitly answer your question, and create a system in which – when the `.information_modify` element is clicked – the text-content of the cells are inserted into an `<input>` element (and a second click on that `.information_modify` element 'saves' the information to the `<table>`, saving to the database is beyond the scope of this question):

```js
// defining a named function to handle the toggling of the editing,
// using Arrow syntax and passing in the Event Object from the use
// of EventTarget.addEventListener():
const editToggle = (evt) => {
  // retrieving the element to which the event-handler was bound:
    let toggle = evt.currentTarget,
      // here we retrieve the closest ancestor <tr> element:
        row = toggle.closest('tr'),
      // and here we create a new <input> element:
      input = document.createElement('input'),
      // retrieving a list of cells from the current <tr>, which
      // have the class of 'canModify':
      editableCells = row.querySelectorAll('.canModify');

  // here we toggle the class of 'editInProgress' on the toggle element's
  // ancestor <tr> and <tbody> elements in order to allow for styling and
  // detection of whether editing is, or is not, in progress:
  row.classList.toggle('editInProgress');
  row.closest('tbody').classList.toggle('editInProgress');
  
  // here we test to see if the ancestor <tr> element has the class of
  // 'editInProgress' in its classList property:
  if (row.classList.contains('editInProgress')) {
    // if so, we're in an editing sitation:
    // here we iterate over the NodeList, using NodeList.prototype.forEach(),
    // along with its anonymous Arrow function:
    editableCells.forEach(
      // 'cell' is a reference to the current <td> of the NodeList of
      // <td> elements over which we're iterating:
      (cell) => {
        // here we clone the created <input> element:
        let clone = input.cloneNode(),
        // we retrieve the value of the data-list attribute, using the
        // HTMLElement.dataset API; though we could instead have  used
        // cell.getAttribute('data-list'):
                dataList = cell.dataset.list;
            
        // we set the <input> element's type property to be equal
        // to the data-type attribute/property:
        clone.type = cell.dataset.type;
        // setting the value of the <input> to be equal to the
        // text-content of the current <td> element, trimming away
        // leading or trailing white-space:
        clone.value = cell.textContent.trim();
        
        // here we use CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty() to set the property
        // of the custom CSS Property '--width' to be equal to the rounded-
        // value of the width of the <td> element; this is because:
        // a: I don't like the way that an <input> of default-width makes the
        //    dimensions of the <table> jump around, and
        // b: trying to use
        //      clone.width = `${Math.round(cell.getBoundingClientRect().width)}px`
        //   didn't seem to work (the width kept being set to 0 in the HTML, despite
        //   retrieving the correct value):
        clone.style.setProperty('--width',`${Math.round(cell.getBoundingClientRect().width)}px`);
        
        // if the dataList is a truthy value (hence it's not
        // undefined, null or an empty-string):
        if (dataList) {
          // we use HTMLElement.setAttribute() to set the
          // attribute-value (dataList) of the 'list' attribute:
            clone.setAttribute('list', dataList);
        }
        
        // we remove the current text-content (having cached it,
        // and set the <input> element's value):
        cell.textContent = '';
        // and append the cloned <input> to the <td>:
        cell.append(clone);
    });
  // otherwise, if the <tr> element does not have the class of 'editInProgress':
  } else {
    // we again iterate over the editableCells, and again in the same manner:
    editableCells.forEach(
        (cell) => {
        // here we retrieve the first/only <input> found within the
        // <td> element:
        let input = cell.querySelector('input'),
            // we retrieve the dataList element from the <input> element's
            // list property:
                dataList = input.list,
            // and recover the current-value of the <input>:
                text = input.value.trim();
        
        // if the dataList is truthy (not null, undefined...),
        // and the text is not an empty string,
        // and an Array formed from the <option> elements of the
        // <datalist> doesn't include the current <input> value:
        if (dataList && text.length > 0 && ![...dataList.options].map((opt)=>opt.text).includes(text)) {
          // we append a new <option> element to the <datalist>, whose
          // text, and therefore value, is set to be equal to the current
          // <input> value (so a new option, such as 'Dr' or 'Lead Administrator'
          // doesn't have to be fully typed out again, should it be required again):
            dataList.append(new Option(text));
        }
        
        // we remove all contents of the <td>:
        cell.innerHTML = '';
        // and we append the text, from the <input> element's value:
        cell.append(text);
    });
  }
},
// caching a NodeList of all '.information_modify' elements:
editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.information_modify');

// iterating over that NodeList, again using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
editButtons.forEach(
  // binding the editToggle() function (note the deliberate lack of parentheses) as
  // the event-handler for the 'click' event:
    (button) => button.addEventListener('click', editToggle)
);
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: clamp(auto, 80vw, 900px);
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

th, td {
  border-block-end: 2px solid #000;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  }
  
.information_modify {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200 200 200 / 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:empty {
  --alpha: 0.5;
  --accent-color: rgb(200 200 200 / var(--alpha));
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 5px, var(--accent-color) 5px 8px);
}

img:empty:hover {
  --alpha: 1;
}

/* highlighting the <td> elements of the currently-selected
   <tr> */
tr.editInProgress > td {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

/* any <td> elements which are not found within a <tr> with
   the class of 'editInProgress' but are found within an
   ancestor (in this case <tbody>) element with the class of
   'editInProgress': */
.editInProgress tr:not(.editInProgress) td {
  /* to give the impression that other <td> elements
     are not interactive while editing in progress: */
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  /* here we set the width of the <input> elements to be either
     equal to the CSS property '--width' or the default width
     of 5em if the '--width' property is invalid for any reason: */
  width: var(--width, 5em);
}
```

```html
<!-- using datalist elements to hold potential options where it
     makes sense to do so:-->
<datalist id="prenom">
  <option>Mr</option>
  <option>Ms</option>
  <option>Mrs</option>
</datalist>
<datalist id="role">
  <option>admin</option>
  <option>analyst</option>
  <option>executive officer</option>
  <option>marketing</option>
  <option>sales</option>
  <option>superuser</option>
  <option>user</option>
</datalist>


<table>
  <caption> Liste des utilisateurs </caption>
  <!-- wrapping the row of <th> elements in a <thead>: -->
  <thead>
    <tr class="title">
      <th>Date de création</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
      <th>Nom d'utilisateur</th>
      <th>Mail</th>
      <th>Rôle</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- wrapping the contents of the <table> in a <tbody>: -->
  <tbody>
    <!-- the fake details here were created from a JS Fiddle I created
         here: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mv2docp7/ feel free to
         play around for your own development needs: -->
    <tr>
      <td>1994-01-31 12:16</td>
      <!-- I added the class of 'canModify' to the elements that it makes sense
           to modify (it doesn't make sense - to me - to modify a user's
           id or creation-date), but adjust to taste.
           I added the custom data-* attributes for use in the JavaScript,
           data-type: determines the <input> type, whereas data-list
           identifies the <datalist> element to be associated to that
           <input>: -->
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Joanne Randall</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">user</td>
      <td>1664</td>
      <!-- an <img>, in a <table>, must be wrapped in either a <th> or
           <td> element; so I wrapped said element in a <td>: -->
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1982-02-19 09:12</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Tim Scott</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">user</td>
      <td>166</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1990-01-25 09:17</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Cameron May</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">marketing</td>
      <td>1736</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1980-01-17 14:01</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Carol Vance</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">sales</td>
      <td>564</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1999-08-01 09:44</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Megan Fraser</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">user</td>
      <td>1804</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1979-11-30 12:21</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Sarah Paterson</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">executive officer</td>
      <td>1164</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1986-10-08 15:25</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Nicholas Morgan</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">admin</td>
      <td>733</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1978-07-19 09:00</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom"></td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">Sam Abraham</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">*****@mail.fr</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">superuser</td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g9zsjqkd/).

The above approach, though, seems a little unnecessary; since a user only *really* needs the illusion of change to enable editing. With that in mind, the following approach retains `<input>` elements within the table-cells and simply changes their style to indicate editing possibilities:

```js
const editToggle = (evt) => {
    let toggle = evt.currentTarget,
      row = toggle.closest('tr');

    row.classList.toggle('editInProgress');
    row.closest('tbody').classList.toggle('editInProgress');

    // here we select, and then iterate over, the NodeList of all <input>
    // elements in the current <tr> element:
    row.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(
      // passing in a reference to the current element (here: <input>) to
      // the body of the anonymous Arrow function:
      (el) => {
        // retrieving the value of the current <input>, and using
        // String.prototype.trim() to remove leading, and trailing,
        // white-space:
        let value = el.value.trim(),
            // retrieving the <datalist> element associated with
            // the current <input>:
            dataList = el.list,
            // if the dataList is truthy (so not null, undefined, false...), we
            // use the conditional ('ternary') operator to return an Array of
            // the text of each <option> of the <datalist>; otherwise we return
            // an empty Array:
            dataListOptions = dataList ? [...dataList.options].map((opt) => opt.text) : [];
            
        // if the dataList is truthy (as above), and the value is not an empty string,
        // and if the dataListOptions Array does not include the current value:
        if (dataList && value.length > 0 && !dataListOptions.includes(value)) {
          // we append a new <option> element to the <datalist>, with its
          // text (and implicit value) set to the value of the current <input>:
          dataList.append(new Option(value));
        }
        
        // if the ancestor <tr> has the class of 'editInProgress':
        if (row.classList.contains('editInProgress')) {
          // we remove the 'readonly' attribute:
          el.removeAttribute('readonly');
        } else {
          // otherwise, we set the readonly attribute:
          el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        }
      })
  },
  // retrieving the NodeList of all elements with the class of 'information_modify':
  editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.information_modify');

// iterating over that NodeList using NodeList.prototype.forEach():
editButtons.forEach(
  // binding the editToggle() function as the event-handler for the 'click' event:
  (button) => button.addEventListener('click', editToggle)
);
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, Montserrat, system-ui;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: clamp(50em, 80vw, 1000px);
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
}

th,
td {
  border-block-end: 2px solid #000;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
}

.information_modify {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200 200 200 / 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img:empty {
  --alpha: 0.5;
  --accent-color: rgb(200 200 200 / var(--alpha));
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0 5px, var(--accent-color) 5px 8px);
}

img:empty:hover {
  --alpha: 1;
}

td {
  max-width: 10.5em;
}

td,
input {
  color: inherit;
}

/* selecting any <td> or <th> element which is the second-child
   of its parent: */
:is(td, th):nth-child(2) {
  /* setting the width to 2em, this is to narrow the 'prenom'
     cells: */
  width: 5em;
}

/* selecting any <td> or <th> element which is the last-child
   of its parent: */
:is(td, th):last-child {
  /* setting its width to 2em, to narrow the last column;
     I set the .information_modify <img> elements to be
     1em in width and height, so adjust to your own requirements: */
  width: 2em;
}

tr.editInProgress>td {
  background-color: #ffa;
}

/* selecting all <td> or <input> elements which are within a <tr>
   element that does not match the selector which is itself in
   another ancestor which has the class of 'editInProgress': */
.editInProgress tr:not(.editInProgress) :is(td, input) {
  /* trying to indicate a lack of interactivity: */
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  /* removing the border of all <input> elements, to remove the
     impression of those elements being an <input>: */
  border: unset;
  outline: none;
  /* setting the width of the elements to the minimum size of
     either 10em or 95% of the parent: */
  width: min(10em, 95%);
}
```

```html
<datalist id="prenom">
  <option>Mr</option>
  <option>Ms</option>
  <option>Mrs</option>
</datalist>
<datalist id="role">
  <option>admin</option>
  <option>analyst</option>
  <option>executive officer</option>
  <option>marketing</option>
  <option>sales</option>
  <option>superuser</option>
  <option>user</option>
</datalist>

<table>
  <caption> Liste des utilisateurs </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr class="title">
      <th>Date de création</th>
      <th>Prénom</th>
      <th>Nom d'utilisateur</th>
      <th>Mail</th>
      <th>Rôle</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1994-01-31 12:16</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Anthony Sutherland" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="user" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>1664</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1982-02-19 09:12</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Owen Ince" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="analyst" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>166</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1990-01-25 09:17</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Sonia Hardacre" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="analyst" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>1736</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1980-01-17 14:01</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Liam Knox" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="superuser" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>564</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1999-08-01 09:44</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Stephanie Mathis" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="admin" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>1804</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1979-11-30 12:21</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Kevin Jackson" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="analyst" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>1164</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1986-10-08 15:25</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Sonia Hardacre" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="superuser" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>733</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1978-07-19 09:00</td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="prenom">
        <input type="text" list="prenom" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text">
        <input type="text" value="Trevor Lawrence" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="email">
        <input type="email" value="*****@mail.fr" readonly>
      </td>
      <td class="canModify" data-type="text" data-list="role">
        <input type="text" list="role" value="user" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>1440</td>
      <td>
        <img class="information_modify" src="chemin" alt="img_modifier">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/g9zsjqkd/).

With the second approach there is the obvious problem that the selection behaviour is noticeably different than if the cell-contents weren't simply 'disguised' `<td>` elements, because of the default (and apparently non-adjustable) `user-select: contain`, which causes a user-selection to be contained within the element in which it started and not to participate in a selection that began elsewhere.

Not to mention that I'm choosing to toggle the presence of the `readonly` attribute on the `<input>` elements.

The preferred approach, I think, will come down to personal preference and project requirements.